# How to have a better looking top and bottom bar in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using gVim on Windows 7, and I've installed a theme for it - it's called materialtheme. When I downloaded this theme, the screenshot showed a different looking top and bottom bar to what I have - here's the screenshot:
[image: The screenshot of the theme]
But, when I install it, I get neither the top or the bottom bar - I assume this might be implemented in some kind of plugin? Mainly what I want is the triangular ends.

So, **how can I get those coloured bars?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for this plugin:

### [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)

[image]

Comment: thanks! This is definitely the right plugin but, it seems to not work completely on windows. As far as I know I can't attach images into my comment so I'll describe it - it seems to work fine apart from where the triangles are, they are simply lesser than and greater than symbols (< and >), instead of solid triangles

Comment: Check this link http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-to-fix-status-bar-symbols-in-airline-plugin

Comment: @Jacob_  you need to edit your question because it was not clear.

Comment: Thanks - I've finally got it working! This was the right answer